# How do I make image slideshows with a fold effect?

Tags: javascript, image, swap

Back in 2000 I had a js that let me get a very nice homepage:

one picture: `<pic src=x>`

and somehow the js changed the main picture every a predefined time period.
(there was a pictures pool that was loaded at pageload)

I can find such scripts now but cannot find one with fold effect 
(like folding a page in a book)

The closet I got was a jQuery solution - but I don't know this technology and I prefer the JS.  Can you please give me a reference to such solution?

Comment: jQuery is Javascript (and, as a note, jQuery would solve your problem pretty easily here).

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search on page fold effects I found this js library:

http://www.netzgesta.de/curl/

There's also a jQuery plug-in for a very similar effect at:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/attractive-jquery-page-curl-plugin/

Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: thanks,I saw it but I know there is a js that in addition to the curl effect, it does an images loop where the change image function uses the curl effect... I know it sounds lazy... but I'm not that good in js and searching and asking for help make more sense in this case. Thanks

Comment: @Asaf,yeah you might have to connect a couple of effect in sequence to get the full effect your looking for.  Good luck.